# Collecting hash entries with identical values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, uniqueidentifier

I have an array that looks like below

```
unorganized_array = [
  {:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'blue',  :texture => 'soft'}]},
  {:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'green', :texture => 'hard'}]},
  {:identifier => '2', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'red',   :texture => 'spiky'}]}]
```

[{:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [
    {:color => 'blue', :texture => 'soft'}]},
    {:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [
    {:color => 'green', :texture => 'hard'}]},
    {{:identifier => '2', :groupinfo =>
    [{:color => 'red', :texture => 'spiky'}]}

I want to collect all the entries with the same `:identifier` into that identifier's `:groupinfo`. This has an extra `:identifier => '2'` group compared to the previous example:

```
organized_array = [{:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [
{:color => 'blue', :texture => 'soft'}, 
{:color => 'green', :texture => 'hard'}]},
{:identifier => '2', :groupinfo =>
[{:color => 'red', :texture => 'spiky'},
{:color => 'gray', :texture => 'squishy}]}]
```

I feel like `Hash#merge` and `Hash#inject` would be useful here but I'm unsure as to how to implement them.

I'm making unorganized_array from an array that looks like

```
original_array = [['blue', 'soft', '1', 'irrelevant'], ['green','hard','1','irrelevant1'],
['red','spiky','2','irrelevant2']]
```

perhaps there is a better method than going from original_array -> unorganized_array -> organized_array?

so far I've been trying to use #map and #each with for loops to group them together, i.e.

```
unorganized_array = original_array.map! do |first, second, third, fourth|
    {:identifier => third, :groupinfo => [{:color => first, :texture => second}]}
end
```

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried so we can help correct your code, rather than write code for you which is totally unrelated to anything you've tried. Please read "[ask]".

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: I made two corrections to your `unorganized_array` (you had `{{:identifier => '2'...` and omitted `]` at the end) and reformatted to make it easier to read. In future, please confirm your inputs are all valid Ruby objects before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unorganized_array.map(&:dup)
                 .group_by { |e| e.delete(:identifier) }
                 .map { |k, v| [k, v.flat_map { |h| h[:groupinfo] } ] }
                 .map { |k, v| { identifier: k, groupinfo: v } }
```

The above gives on the input shown:

```
#⇒ [ { :groupinfo => [ 
#         { :color => "blue", :texture => "soft" },
#         { :color => "green", :texture => "hard" } ],
#      :identifier => "1" },
#    { :groupinfo => [
#         { :color => "red", :texture => "spiky" } ],
#      :identifier => "2" } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're generating an Array of 2-key Hashes, the second of which contains an Array of attributes.  Why not instead use the "identifier" as your `key` for a `Hash`?  After all, that's precisely what a key is.

This seems cleaner:

```
{"1"=>[{:color=>"blue", :texture=>"soft"}, 
       {:color=>"green", :texture=>"hard"}], 
"2"=>[{:color=>"red", :texture=>"spiky"}]}
```

And here's one way of generating this:

```
my_hash = original_array.reduce({}) do |r,s| 
  r.merge( s[2] => (r[s[2]] || []) + [{color: s[0], texture: s[1]}] )
end
```

To @the Tin Man's point, understanding Ruby's `Enumerable` class is a more worthy objective than discovery of any particular solution we can provide.

---

#### Working with your Hash

Here's one way of iterating through all your items.

```
my_hash.each do |key,arr| 
  puts "Identifier \##{key} has #{arr.size} items"
  arr.each_with_index do |item,index|
    puts "Item \##{index+1} is #{item[:color]} and #{item[:texture]}"
  end
end
```

Outputs:

```
Identifier #1 has 2 items
Item #1 is blue and soft
Item #2 is green and hard
Identifier #2 has 1 items
Item #1 is red and spiky
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the key as a string? I needed `identifier` previously because "1" was necessary in further code, and `[:identifier]` was an easy way to get it.

Comment: Yup.  Everything stored in a Hash is accessible, it's just a matter of becoming comfortable with the associated methods.  See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr =
  [{:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'blue,   :texture => 'soft}]},
   {:identifier => '1', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'green', :texture => 'hard'}]},
   {:identifier => '2', :groupinfo => [{:color => 'red',   :texture => 'spiky'}]}]
```

There are a couple of ways you can do this by building hashes.

**Use the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that employs a default that determines `h[k]` when the hash `h` does not have a key `k`.**

```
hash_with_default = Hash.new { |h,k| { identifier: k, groupdata: [] } }

arr.each_with_object(hash_with_default) { |g,h| h[g[:identifier]] =
  { identifier: g[:identifier],
    groupdata:  h[g[:identifier]][:groupdata] << g[:groupinfo].first } }.values
  #=> [{:identifier=>"1", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"blue", :texture=>"soft"},
  #                                    {:color=>"green", :texture=>"hard"}]},
  #    {:identifier=>"2", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"red", :texture=>"spiky"}]}]
```

**Use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:identifier] => g) { |k,o,n|
  { identifier: o[:identifier], groupinfo: h[k][:groupinfo] + g[:groupinfo] } } }.values
  #=> [{:identifier=>"1", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"blue", :texture=>"soft"},
  #                                    {:color=>"green", :texture=>"hard"}]},
  #    {:identifier=>"2", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"red", :texture=>"spiky"}]}]
```

Please consult the doc for the meanings of the three block variables, `k`, `o` and `n`.

Comment: Love your answers, @Cary. Your usage of `Hash`#`update` with a `block` here is really cool. You're like `Ruby` MacGyver.

Comment: @Cam. Not at all. As I recall, Mrs. MacGyver was short and squat, and female.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best way but I suggested to do:

1- group your array by identifier

```
unorganized_array.group_by{|x| x[:identifier]}
#=>  {"1"=>[{:identifier=>"1", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"blue", :texture=>"soft"}]},
{:identifier=>"1", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"green", :texture=>"hard"}]}],
"2"=>[{:identifier=>"2", :groupinfo=>[{:color=>"red", :texture=>"spiky"}]}]}
```

2 - collect your grouped_array elements in the expected hash and collect the group info values. Now every element into the array contains related items.

```
group_array.each.collect {|k,g| { :identifier => k, :group_info => g.collect{ |x| x[:groupinfo].last } } }
```

3- result is the organized array

```
[{:identifier=>"1", :group_info=>[
 {:color=>"blue", :texture=>"soft"}, 
 {:color=>"green", :texture=>"hard"}
]}, 
{:identifier=>"2", :group_info=>[{:color=>"red", :texture=>"spiky"}]}]
```